# Find $a\in\mathbb{C}$ so that the equation of the line through $−2 + i$ and $−2i$ is $z\bar{a} − a\bar{z} = 8i$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the following geometry problem:

Find $a\in\mathbb{C}$ so that the equation of the line through $−2 + i$ and $−2i$ is $$z\bar{a} − a\bar{z} = 8i$$
where the bar represents the complex conjugate.

I feel like I am almost there, but seem to be missing something. Here is what I have so far.

Attempt:

Let $a$ be the point on the line $[b,c]$ such that $z\bar{a} − a\bar{z} = 8i$. Then
\begin{align}
b=-2i&\Rightarrow \bar{b}=2i\\
c=-2+i&\Rightarrow \bar{c}=-2-i
\end{align}
Now, we are given 2 points and must find the third point, denoted $a$. I believe this would be the same as showing linear dependence. That is show that
\begin{equation}
det\left|\begin{array}{l}
a&\bar{a}&1\\
b&\bar{b}&1\\
c&\bar{c}&1\end{array}\right|=0
\end{equation}
With a bit of linear algebra we find the determinant gives us
$$(b-a)(\bar{c}-\bar{a})-(\bar{b}-\bar{a})(c-a)=0$$
and making our substitutions for $b,\bar{b},c$ and $\bar{c}$ we have the following expression

$$(-2i-a)(-2-i-\bar{a})-(2i-\bar{a})(-2+1-a)=0.$$

Expanding this we get

$$-4-2a+2\bar{a}-6ai=8i$$

and with some rearranging we have

$$4-2\bar{a}-(2-6i)a=8i.$$

Now, this does look similar to what I am trying to find, but I'm not sure I see the $z$ and $\bar{z}$. I am wondering if there is a step at the beginning I missed, or is there something I need to do next to get the result I require.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy, a=c-id$ where $x,y,c,d$ are real

$8i=z\bar a-\bar za=2i(dx+cy)\iff dx+cy=4$

If $z=-2i;x=0,y=-2\implies -2c=4\iff c=?$

If $z=-2+i;x=-2,y=1\implies-2d+c=4$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Well that seems far easier than the route I was taking. Thank you, yes I can take it from here.